# django models - conditionally set blank=True

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to build an app, where user can customize forms. The Following example contains classes for creating Fields (`QuestionField`, `AnswerField`) which is used by the admin and the `BoolAnswer` which is filled by the user: This Way an admin can create a Form with questions and possible answers.

According to django documentation, `blank=True` is related to evaluation. The problem is that it is set on the class level rather than on object level.

How can I set `blank=True` depending on the related model so that I do not have to reimplement an own validator? (see pseudo code in `BoolAnswer`)

My `models.py`:

```
class QuestionField(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    models.ForeignKey(Sheet)


class BoolAnswerField(AnswerField):
    question = models.ForeignKey(models.Model)
    if_true_field = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)


class BoolAnswer(models.Model):
    bool_answer_field = models.ForeignKey(BoolAnswerField)
    result = models.BooleanField()
    if_true = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True,

                               blank=True if self.bool_answer_field.if_true_field)
```

** Short explanation **:
If the Answer to a `BoolAnswerField` question is True, `if_true` field should explain, why

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't hate me, but validation is the way to go, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean_fields)

```
class BoolAnswer(models.Model):
    bool_answer_field = models.ForeignKey(BoolAnswerField)
    result = models.BooleanField()
    if_true = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def clean(self)
        if self.bool_answer_field.if_true_field and not self.if_true:
            raise ValidationError('BAF is True without a reason')
```

In case you want your error message to be displayed next to the field, not at the beginning of the form, you've got to pass a `dict` to `ValidationError`, like:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
...
raise ValidationError({
    'field_name': _('This field is required.')})
```

Comment: I think you 're right, just thought I would need to do custom validation on form level.

Comment: It's better to do this validation at the model so that you can use ModelForm (which changes the instance being validated / it isn't recommended to overwrite `ModelForm.clean()`.